# Efficienctly convert List<Object> to Object[][]

Tags: java, swing

I currently have a List of Student objects that I need to convert to Object[][] so that I can append the data into my JTable in GUI, I'm kind of lost as to how to do it in an efficient/dynamic manner.

I don't have anything written down to post here, I can give you the details of the data:

```
List<Student> myStudents = new ArrayList<>();
```

Needs to somehow be morphed to:

```
Object[][] data = {{...}};
```

Each student has 11 fields to be added, so it would go to Object[i][0 .. 10]

The alternative to all of this, is to somehow find a way to pass `List<Student>` inside `new JTable(data, columnNames)` instead of `Object[][]`

Either or would solve this issue

Comment: you would typically need a modulo, and 2 indices, and then a loop.

Comment: Won't Object[] enough?

Comment: @njzk2 Thanks, mind elaborating on that though? Pankaj - No Object[] wouldn't work as each JTable takes Object[][] and each Student has multiple elements in itself

Comment: so each Object[] would represent one complete student?

Comment: Theoretically yes, however I need to access the data inside each Student separately, therefore it won't allow me to pass Object[] to JTable()

Comment: @Juxhin Or you can use a TableModel http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Comment: Assuming each `Student` has 11 member values (getter methods) you care about, you are not going to get much better than iterating over the list and creating the sub-arrays yourself.  You could use reflection but then you need to have a way to map the members/getters to array positions.  Without more detail (i.e. what does a `Student` look like) this question is too vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The alternative to all of this, is to somehow find a way to pass List inside new JTable(data, columnNames)

This is the better approach. You should never try to keep two copies of the data. All the data should only be stored in the TableModel. This means you need to create a custom TableModel to hold the Student objects.

Check out [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a basic implementation of a TableModel that can support any custom Object. You will need to implement a couple of methods to support your Student Object. The `JButtonTableModel` examples shows you how this can be done.

Comment: So far I've worked with AbstractTableModel, whould I opt for RowTableModel instead?

Comment: @Juxhin: `Row Table Model` _is an_ `AbstractTableModel`

Comment: @Juxhin, you are using a class that extends AbstractTableModel, probably the DefaultTableModel. You have a problem and asked a question because the design of the DefaultTableModel causes you to have the data in two places, which is not a good design. I gave you an alternative solution which provides a better design. Did you even bother to look at the blog or the code before making your comment?

Comment: Hey @camickr Sorry for the late, reply, I'm definitely using your method as opposed to my initial idea for the reason you mentioned, doesn't make sense to convert the objects back and forth. I'm still reading the blog you sent me, it's relatively long and I'm trying to absorb as much of it as I can

Comment: Gave everything a good look, whilst I don't haven't grasped is ALL just yet, this answer fits my situation the best. Thanks @camickr

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like that, you won't get any simpler, unless there is something to know about Student

```
List<Object[]> props = new ArrayList<>();

for (Student student : myStudents) {
    Object[] std = new Object[11];
    std[0] = student.whatever;
    // Complete the object
    props.add(std);
}

return props.toArray();
```

Comment: Code works great! However, wouldn't this still return Object[]?

Comment: @Juxhin props is a list of arrays, so props.toArray returns an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert in JTable so this may not be the best solution.

```
Object[][] data = new Object[myStudents.size()][11];
for(int i = 0; i < myStudents.size(); i++) {
    data[i][0] = myStudents.get(i).firstProperty;
    data[i][1] = myStudents.get(i).secondProperty;
    // continue
}
```