# JTable AbstractTableModel not firing dynamic List of data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I've managed to lurk around and find a good class which offers to substitute `JTable(Object[][] data, Object[] columnNames)` with `RowTableModel(List<T> modelData, List<String> columnNames)` instead which is great as it allows me to dynamic add my Student data directly from my students.ser file.

After spending God knows how long, I haven't been able to fix a strange issue. The table is displaying everything properly except the data inside itself.

---

This is the current result:
[image]

Obviously those empty rows are the number of Student that I have(5 in this case), however none of the data is printed.

My thought is that I need to assign a specific Student field to each column, Eg. For row Name I assign Student.getName()

---

If you would like to check out [RowTableModel](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/)

Here is the documented class methods/constructors that I've used:

**Constructor**

```
/**
 *  Constructs a <code>RowTableModel</code> with initial data and
 *  customized column names.
 *
 *  Each item in the <code>modelData</code> List must also be a List Object
 *  containing items for each column of the row.
 *
 *  Each column's name will be taken from the <code>columnNames</code>
 *  List and the number of colums is determined by thenumber of items
 *  in the <code>columnNames</code> List.
 *
 *  Sub classes creating a model using this constructor must make sure
 *  to invoke the setRowClass() method.
 *
 * @param modelData      the data of the table
 * @param columnNames      <code>List</code> containing the names
 *                          of the new columns
 */
protected RowTableModel(List<T> modelData, List<String> columnNames)
{
    setDataAndColumnNames(modelData, columnNames);
}
```

**setDataAndColumnNames:**

```
/**
 *  Reset the data and column names of the model.
 *
 *  A fireTableStructureChanged event will be generated.
 *
 * @param modelData      the data of the table
 * @param columnNames      <code>List</code> containing the names
 *                          of the new columns
 */
protected void setDataAndColumnNames(List<T> modelData, List<String> columnNames)
{
    this.modelData = modelData;
    this.columnNames = columnNames;
    columnClasses = new Class[getColumnCount()];
    isColumnEditable = new Boolean[getColumnCount()];
    fireTableStructureChanged();
}
```

---

**getValueAt(int row, int col) - Working code!:**

```
@Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        Student myStudent = getRow(row);
        switch(col){
            case 1: return students.get(row).getTeacherId();
            case 2: return students.get(row).getId();
            case 3: return students.get(row).getName();
            case 4: return students.get(row).getSurname();
            case 5: return students.get(row).getEmail();
            case 6: return students.get(row).getDateOfBirth();
            case 7: return students.get(row).getTel();
            case 8: return students.get(row).getCourse();
            case 9: return students.get(row).isOOP();
            case 10: return students.get(row).getYearOfMembership();
            case 11: return students.get(row).hasConsent();
            default: return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you assigned the `RowTableModel` to the table?  Is it the same instance?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I have it assigned to RowTableModel

Comment: this code made by @camickr required middle_level of knowledge about How JTable and its XxxTableModel (really) works

Comment: Yea I figured that out, basically spent the past 2 days reading about JTables

Comment: better, faster more confortable will be to use DefaultTableModel, in all cases except largest tables and updated periodically,

Comment: That's what I used, however it doesn't accept List<> as parameters and converting List to Object[][] sounds like a very inefficient way to tackle the issue don't you think?

Comment: XxxTableModel is array too, in most cases isn't neccessary to hold two or more arrays in one program, nor in the case that contians the same data, shoutcut ---> here are bunch of AbstractTableModels based on List, especially @MadProgrammer posted here a few attempts about in SSCCE/MCVE form (close to perfection)

Comment: @mKorbel I see, the XxxTableModel I posted does work on List<>, the only 'issue'(pretty sure it's minor) is that fact that it doesn't actually FIRE the data inside my Student Object to the table cells. What I'm presuming is that I need to set the [row][col] to fit my Student object. If col = 1, then students.get(row).getTeacherId() as Teacher ID is my first field. I however may be completely wrong. I've avoided the idea of having multiple arrays, that isn't the proper way to handle the situation

Comment: @Juxhin, Posting a few random lines of code from the class doesn't help. The code from that class works. The problem is with the custom code that you implemented for the `getValueAt()` method and the `setValueAt()` methods if you want the table to be editable. You need to post your custom code since for any question you ask the code you write is where the problem is going to be.

Comment: @camickr You're right. I've went ahead and tried adding the setValueAt(), if that's the proper way to write it, I'll do the same for getValueAt() (Obviously returning values)

Comment: @Juxhin, No that setValueAt() code is not correct. The `RowTableModel`, does NOT use a 2Dimensional array to store the data. I gave you a working example in the blog. Your code looks nothing like the code in my example. Did you even download the example code and execute the code to see how it works???

Comment: @camickr Yes I have, it seems I didn't quite grasp the whole thing so this question is pointless for now. Feel free to lock it

Comment: @Juxhin, I posted an example with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it seems I didn't quite grasp the whole thing

It may take a while but I have to ask why doesn't your code look anything like the code in the example? Where in the example do I reference a 2Dimensional Array?

All you are trying to do is display a `Student` object instead of a `JButton` object. So basically all you need to do is change all references of JButton to Student and then fill out the properties for the Student.

So once again I ask, where is the code that shows how you extended the RowTableModel? What part of the getValueAt() method do you not understand?

The code from the example is:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
{
    JButton button = getRow(row);

    switch (column)
    {
        case 0: return button.getText();
        case 1: return button.getToolTipText();
        case 2: return button.isEnabled();
        case 3: return button.isVisible();
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

You are not storing JButton objects in the model so you change the code for your Student Object. Something like:

```
@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column)
{
    Student student = getRow(row);

    switch (column)
    {
        case 0: return student.getTeacherId();
        case 1: return student.getId();
        case 2: return ...;
        case 3: return ...;
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

We are not mind readers. We don't know what is confusing you. If you don't ask a specific question then how do you expect us to help? That is why you post you code so we can better understand what you are trying to do or have done.

Comment: Before tackling the answer I'd like to say thanks. Since I self taught everything, speaking formally in terms of programming was never my forté and thus find it difficult to explain what my issue is.

Comment: Managed to get it to work, all of a sudden everything fit like a jigsaw puzzle. Don't understand how I wasn't able to figure it out beforehand. Thanks a million, your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

From the [link](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) you had given :

> The **RowTableModel** is an abstract class. It **does not implement** the **getValueAt()** or **setValueAt()** methods of the TableModel. This will allow you to extend the model to support row Objects of any type in the model. You will only need to extend this class to implement these methods for your particular row Object type. For a simple example of how this might be done see the [**JButtonTableModel**](http://www.camick.com/java/source/JButtonTableModel.java) example code found below.

If those methods aren't implemented, the `JTable` will not be able to interrogate the table data model. So the data passed in the constructor will not be used.

Please see [the Java Doc for TableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

Comment: +1, In the OP's previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25295470/131872), I also stressed `You will need to implement a couple of methods to support your Student Object. The JButtonTableModel examples shows you how this can be done.` I guess I wasn't clear enough. Thanks for stressing this point. The OP must have provided some kink of implementation since the code compiled, but since the OP didn't provide the custom code used we can't really help.